# How to block all ports for specific public ips using fail2ban with iptables

Tags: fail2ban

Kindly share the steps how to block all ports with specific public ips using fail2ban with iptables. I want to block all ports for the given ips by me and share the file name too. where i need to configure.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?/Do you want to ban all ports when fail2ban triggers or do you want to ban IPs from a list? What does a filename have to do with anything?

Comment: Eh... Fail2Ban does not block individual ports, but instead the entire IP address by default. It does it by monitoring whatever log you want to monitor, by looking for string patterns. If a pattern matches a specific IP address a number of times (default is 5), then the IP address will be blocked.

Comment: @LasseMichaelMolgaard not so - it can do whatever action you ask it to. Most out-the-box configurations have options to ban a port, multiple ports or everything.

Comment: Okay, I see. Default action is just block all ports. Which serves me fine, since I managed to block an entire /22 subnet from a Chinese and a Iranian ISP due to "hacking attempts". That was basically many bots trying to log into the user "root" with the password "password" on miscellaneous services on my server.

Answer (score 4):

Use `banaction=iptables-allports` instead of `iptables-multiport`.